# Is $G$ is homeomorphic to $X$.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $X$ be a metric space and $f:X\to \Bbb R$ be a continuous function.Let $G=\{(x,f(x):x\in X\}$ be the graph of $f$.Then:

1. $G$ is homeomorphic to $X$.
2. $G$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$.
3. $G$ is homeomorphic to $X\times \Bbb R$.
4. $G$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R\times X$.

**My try**:

2.Let $X=\{a\}$ Then $f(x)=x$ is continuous and $G=\{a,f(a)\}$ which is not homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$

3.$X=\Bbb R;f(x)=0\implies G(f)=\{(x,0):x\in \Bbb R\}$  which is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$ and not to $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R$

4.Same as 3

1.I am unable to solve this case.Please help me out.

Comment: (1) is true. *Corollary*: your counterexample for (2) is wrong. :)

Comment: Please help where I am wrong@G.Sassatelli

Comment: Pick two points of the form $(x,f(x))$ and $(y,f(y))$, with $f$ continuous. Then, $[0,1]\ni t\mapsto (\,x+t(y-x),\, f(x+t(y-x))\,)$ is a path in $G$ connecting them. On the other hand, if $X$ is a point (or *two* points), what's $G$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$r(x) = (x,f(x))$ maps $X$ to $G$ and is continuous and a bijection. The inverse mapping $(x,f(x)) \to x$ is continuous, to see this take any sequence $w_n = (x_n,f(x_n))$ that converges, then it is easy to see $r^{-1}(w_n) = x_n$ must also converge.

Comment: Continuity of the inverse also follows more primitively from continuity of any projection map of any product topology $A \times B \mapsto A$.

Comment: See also [this proof for topological spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4614279/386889) (non necessarily metrizable).