# Proving a homeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, algebraic-topology, solution-verification

> Let $a<b$ be real numbers and $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function into $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the standard topology. Show that the graph \begin{equation}\Gamma_f=\{(x,f(x)):x\in(a,b)\}\end{equation} is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the standard topology.

Attempt: in order to show a function $g:(X,\tau_X)\to (Y,\tau_Y)$ is a homeomorphism, we need to show it is bijective, continuous, and that $g^{-1}$ is continuous. In this problem, we need to show that $f$ satisfies these conditions. It is continuous as given in the problem, but the remaining two axioms that it needs to satisfy aren't clear. I wonder if I've misunderstood and that it's not $f$ we needs to show satisfies the axioms, but I cannot see what else.

Comment: Your doubt is correct; it is not $f$ which needs to satisfy those conditions. Note that if $f$ did, then it would give a homeomorphism between its domain and codomain, $(a,b)$ and $\mathbb{R}$, not $\Gamma_f$ and $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You need to give a potential homeo $h: \mathbb{R} \to \Gamma_f$ (or vice versa) and then check that $h$ (not $f$) satisfies the conditions.

Comment: @Randall I can't think of such a $h$. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, because I know a homeo between $(a,b)$ and $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: This is covered by my answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4614228.