# How can I check that $(x,y)\mapsto (x,y,xy)$ is a regular surface patch?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry, surfaces

> Let me consider the map $$f:\Bbb{R}^2\rightarrow \Bbb{R}^3,~~~(x,y)\mapsto (x,y,xy)$$ I want to check if it is a regular surface patch.

We had the following definition:

> $f:V\rightarrow \Bbb{R}^3$, $V\subset \Bbb{R}^2$ open is a regular surface patch if
>
> 1. $f$ is smooth, i.e. $f^{(n)}$ exists and is continuous for all $n\in \Bbb{N}$
> 2. $f$ is a homeomorphism on $f(V)$
> 3. the differential $df$ is injective

I mean clearly $f$ is smooth since $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y)=(1,0,y)$, $\frac{\partial^{(n)}}{\partial x^{(n)}} f(x,y)=(0,0,0)$ for all $n\geq 2$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x,y)=(0,1,x)$, $\frac{\partial^{(n)}}{\partial y^{(n)}} f(x,y)=(0,0,0)$ for all $n\geq 2$  so all derivatives exists and are continuous.  Furthermore we see that $$df=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
y &x
\end{pmatrix}$$ then if we consider the minor $$D:=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$ we see that $\det(D)=1\neq 0$ so $df$ is injective.

But now I have troubles in checking that it is a homeomorphism on $f(V)$. Can someone help me further?

Comment: It’s probably easiest to explicitly find a continuous inverse here.

Comment: @noam.szyfer thanks for your comment. I thought about it but I don't see it. I mean the inverse should be something like $g(x,y,z)=(g_1(x,y,z), g_2(x,y,z))$ for some functions $g_1,g_2$ depending on $(x,y,z)$ but I mean I want that $f(g(x,y,z))=f(g_1(x,y,z),g_2(x,y,z))=(x,y,z)$ but $f(g_1(x,y,z),g_2(x,y,z))=(g_1(x,y,z), g_2(x,y,z), g_1(x,y,z)g_2(x,y,z))$ but somehow I then think $g_1(x,y,z)=x$ and $g_2(x,y,z)=y$ but then for the third coordinate I get in trouble

Comment: You only need to define an inverse on $f(\mathbb{R}^2)$, not on the whole $\mathbb{R}^3$. So you don’t need to consider any $(x,y,z)$ but only points that have a certain form… Does that help?

Comment: @noam.szyfer ah sorry I have forgot about this. I think now everything is clear because I always thought about a general $z$ which would not work but now it works because I can define on$f(\Bbb{R}^2)=\{(x,y,xy): x,y\in \Bbb{R}\}$ an inverse by  $f^{-1}(x,y,xy)=(x,y)$ because then $f(f^{-1}(x,y,xy))=f(x,y)=(x,y,xy)$ and $f^{-1}(f(x,y))=f^{-1}(x,y,xy)=(x,y)$ right?

Comment: Looks good! To be fully complete all you have to do now is argue why your inverse is continuous, but here there should be no trouble

Answer (score 2):

Let $p : \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^2, p(x,y,z) = (x,y)$. Then $p \circ f = id_{\mathbb R^2}$ which shows that $f$ is injective. Let $V' = f(V)$. Since $f$ is injective, we see that $f' : V \xrightarrow{f} V'$ is a continuous bijection. But $p(V') = p(f(V)) = V$, thus $p$ restricts to a continuous $p' : V' \to V$. By construction $p' \circ f' = id_V$, thus $(f')^{-1} = id_V \circ  (f')^{-1} = p' \circ f' \circ  (f')^{-1} = p'$ which shows that the inverse $(f')^{-1}$ of $f'$ is continuous.

Note that $V'$ is nothing else than the graph of the function $\phi : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R, \phi(x,y) = xy$. It is a general theorem that the graph of a continuous function $u : X \to Y$ which is the subspace
$$G(u) = \{ (x,u(x)) \mid x \in X \} \subset X \times Y$$
is homeomorphic to $X$ via
$$h : X \to G(u), h(x) = (x,u(x)) .$$

You can easily generalize the above proof.

Also see [https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4614228}](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4614228%7D).